# Multiple Forms' Responses Linked to One Single Spreasheet (separate sheets)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I am wondering if it's possible to link multiple forms to one single spreadsheet but on separate sheets.

For example:
I would like responses of "form 1" and "form 2" to be placed in "sheet 1" and "sheet 2" of "spreadsheet ABC" respectively.

I know you cannot do this in the current form interface. It would you this error "The selected document is already the destination for a form.Choose another destination". I am curious if you could do this through Google Apps Scripts (perhaps Forms Services).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As a global rule what you can't do using standard UI can't be done with script, they both work on the same "engine". I didn't test this use case but I would really be very surprised if it was possible. Why don't you simply try?

Comment: I guess I will try tomorrow when I have the time. I will report back. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personally I have several forms linked to the same spreadsheet on separate sheets.

When you create the forms should have the option:

Responses -> Change response destination

[image]

**UPDATE**

This functionality is available in the [new Google Sheets](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3541068). See: [Choose a form response destination](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2917686?hl=en).

Comment: wchiquito, I tried it didn't work. Maybe I did something wrong...What I did was having Form 1 linked to a Spreadsheet ABC and then tried to change the response destination of Form 2 to Spreadsheet ABC choosing the option "New sheet in an existing spreasheet..." but got this error "The selected document is already the destination for a form.Choose another destination".

Comment: @s2000coder: In a small test done a few moments ago, I created two forms and the link to the same spreadsheet on separate sheets. What else can you tell us to see how we can help?

Comment: @s2000coder: "A spreadsheet can collect responses from only one form at a time unless you have switched to the new Google Sheets, which allows responses from multiple forms to be stored in the same spreadsheet." See: [Choose a form response destination](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2917686?hl=en)

Comment: wchiquito, thanks for clarification. I was not using the "NEW" Google Sheets and thus I was unable to linked 2 forms into one spreadsheet. Using the "NEW" Google Sheets, this feature works. Could you add something about the "NEW" Google Sheets in your answer to make it clearer for those who are unaware of a newer version of Google Sheets? I will accept it as the answer.

Comment: @wchiquito : another info I was missing ! thanks and +1